# django-paypal setup for PDT gives me an error

Tags: django, django-paypal

I am using dcramers version of django-paypal[1]. I am trying to use PDT with subscriptions with my sandbox business paypal account `xpanta_XXX_biz@paypal.com`

this is my views.py[2]:

```
def subscribe_confirmation(request, username):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404(u'User not Found')
    paypal_dict = {
        "cmd": "_xclick-subscriptions",
        "business": "xpanta_XXX_biz@gmail.com",
        "a3": "9.99",                      # monthly price
        "p3": 1,                           # duration of each unit (depends on unit)
        "t3": "M",                         # duration unit ("M for Month")
        "src": "1",                        # make payments recur
        "sra": "1",                        # reattempt payment on payment error
        "no_note": "1",                    # remove extra notes (optional)
        "item_name": "monthly subscription",
        "notify_url": "http://mydomain.com/paypal/pdt/",
        "return_url": "http://mydomain.com/pp_success/%s/" % username,
        "cancel_return": "http://mydomain.com/pp_cancel/%s/" % username,
    }

    # Create the instance.
    form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict, button_type="subscribe")
    variables = RequestContext(request, {'user': user, 'form': form, 'type': 'monthly', 'price': '9.99'})
    return render_to_response("subscribe_confirm.html", variables)
```

However, when I login to the paypal site in order to test-subscribe to my service (using my normal paypal credentials. For some reason I can't use my personal sandbox account `xpanta_XXX_per@gmail.com` in order to test the payment system) I get this error:

`The link you have used to enter the PayPal system is invalid. Please review the link and try again.`

There is a "Return to Merchant" button at the bottom of the error which returns me to the cancel page (as expected).

What am I doing wrong?

PS: Adding `urls.py` section:

```
(...
    url(r'^pp_success/(\w+)/$', pp_success),
    url(r'^pp_cancel/(\w+)/$', pp_cancel),
...)

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^paypal/pdt/', include('paypal.standard.pdt.urls')),
)
```

[1] https://github.com/dcramer/django-paypal

[2] Other steps described in the readme file (section "Using PayPal Payments Standard PDT") are unaltered and done exactly as described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the answer.

in the readme file it says that in order to render the form in the template we need to do this: `{{ form.render }}`

It doesn't say, whatsoever, that if you need to use your sandbox account you need to render it like this:

`{{ form.sandbox }}`